# What is the new syntax for `nmcli show` and `nmcli modify`?

Tags: command-line, network-manager, nmcli

This has been asked before at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/114364/nmcli-no-longer-allow-settings-modification - but never answered. So I'll try asking here:

You can see from diverse posts on the net, that the command-line Network Manager used to support something like (from https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Networking_Guide/sec-Using_the_NetworkManager_Command_Line_Tool_nmcli.html):

```
$ nmcli connection show id 'MyCafe'
$ nmcli connection modify id 'MyCafe' 802-11-wireless.mtu 1350
```

Right now, I have on Ubuntu 14.04:

```
$ nmcli --version
nmcli tool, version 0.9.8.8
```

... and I get:

```
$ nmcli con modify
Usage: nmcli connection { COMMAND | help }
  COMMAND := { list | status | up | down | delete }

  list [id <id> | uuid <id>]
  status [id <id> | uuid <id> | path <path>]
  up id <id> | uuid <id> [iface <iface>] [ap <BSSID>] [--nowait] [--timeout <timeout>]
  down id <id> | uuid <id>
  delete id <id> | uuid <id>

Error: 'con' command 'modify' is not valid.

$ nmcli con show
Usage: nmcli connection { COMMAND | help }
  COMMAND := { list | status | up | down | delete }

  list [id <id> | uuid <id>]
  status [id <id> | uuid <id> | path <path>]
  up id <id> | uuid <id> [iface <iface>] [ap <BSSID>] [--nowait] [--timeout <timeout>]
  down id <id> | uuid <id>
  delete id <id> | uuid <id>

Error: 'con' command 'show' is not valid.
```

So, what is the equivalent for `nmcli con show` and `nmcli con modify` syntax, now that these keywords don't exist anymore?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have it the other way around. These options were recently introduced, not recently removed. `nmcli` on Ubuntu 16.04 does have these options:

```
$ nmcli --version
nmcli tool, version 1.2.2
$ nmcli con --help
Usage: nmcli connection { COMMAND | help }

COMMAND := { show | up | down | add | modify | edit | delete | monitor | reload | load }

  show [--active] [--order <order spec>]
  show [--active] [id | uuid | path | apath] <ID> ...

  up [[id | uuid | path] <ID>] [ifname <ifname>] [ap <BSSID>] [passwd-file <file with passwords>]

  down [id | uuid | path | apath] <ID> ...

  add COMMON_OPTIONS TYPE_SPECIFIC_OPTIONS SLAVE_OPTIONS IP_OPTIONS [-- ([+|-]<setting>.<property> <value>)+]

  modify [--temporary] [id | uuid | path] <ID> ([+|-]<setting>.<property> <value>)+

  clone [--temporary] [id | uuid | path ] <ID> <new name>
  ...
```

`nmcli` on 14.04 (0.9.8.8) doesn't have these options, because they were introduced in a later version.

Comment: Many thanks @muru - I could have sworn I looked at this some year(s) ago, and it looked to me as if these features were removed - but from your paste, I can see I was wrong. Great to have this documented, though!

Comment: @sdbbs when in doubt, you could always check the online manpages: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/cgi-bin/search.py?q=nmcli (compare 16.04 vs 14.04)